# Metadata Display Issue When Sharing on Facebook and LinkedIn

Tags: angular, angular-ssr

I'm facing a technical issue when sharing pages from my website on Facebook or LinkedIn. I'm using Angular Universal (SSR) for server-side rendering and have implemented SEO strategies for search engine optimization.

However, when sharing a page, the metadata correctly configured in the `<head>` section of the page is not being displayed properly on these platforms. Despite the metadata's validity confirmed through direct inspection in the browser, the URL extraction in the specific debuggers of Facebook or LinkedIn does not reflect the expected metadata.

Furthermore, I utilize Resolve to preload data in components, aiming to avoid delays in page updates. The choice for Resolve was motivated by the need for integration with an external API.

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this technical issue related to metadata display when sharing on Facebook and LinkedIn.

Comment: Have you tested using the [sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)? There you have the option to clear the cached response for urls

Comment: Already did that. It appears that Facebook and LinkedIn crawlers do not wait for server-side rendering.
Tracker X (Twitter) awaits. I run the On-Page Seo Checker SEO tool and it shows the Linkedin share preview.